# When will I be able to start a bounty on my questions?

Tags: support, bounty

[What would you add in this Software Development Project Checklist?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22504/what-would-you-add-in-this-software-development-project-checklist)

I would like to start a bounty there. It's not always possible. What are the rules?

Comment: I got my answer in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

- Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
- Users must have at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.
- There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.
- Once initiated, the bounty period lasts 7 days.
- After starting a bounty, you must wait 1 day before awarding it.
- If you do not award your bounty within 7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.